# Create random data that is increasing towards a particular point

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I am trying to create random data between two data points. I want a generally increasing trend towards a a particular point. I have roughly drawn what I want in the diagram below:

[image]

I tried out a couple of solutions including the truncated normal distribution, but can't seem to make this happen.

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: This is the sort of question I have seen physics undergrads ask when they didn't schedule the proper lab time and the report is due tomorrow :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Definitely not one, but got something due tomorrow indeed.

Comment: I'm sure that the concept is transferable to many disciplines :)

Comment: Does this show the intended distribution function or how should we interpret this plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add white noise to the data. It works better in conjunction with the other methods shown, but can also be used on its own if you don't need to have a lot of structure in your noise:

```
x = np.linspace(0, x_max, n_points)
y = np.linspace(0, y_max, n_points) + np.random.normal(size=n_points)
```

If you want the endpoints to be fixed, you have to hold them constant:

```
y = np.linspace(0, y_max, n_points)
y[1:-1] += np.random.normal(size=n_points - 2)
```

Comment: This is a great solution, what if I do not have data to begin with?

Comment: @Sharan Duggirala: I think you must have some rules or ideas about (x_max, y_max), haven't you ? How are they ?

Comment: @Sharan. I include the data and the noise. The first term of `y` is a perfect line, the second is the noise. I still think you're better off using coldspeed's solution for the first term in `y`.

Comment: @coldspeed. Please don't delete your answer. I much prefer it to mine, and normalizing by the last element of the cumsum is trivial. I think random walks are much prettier than white noise, and usually make for more realistic fake data.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to create a line segment that starts and ends at the positions you want. Next take its midpoint and move it a random amount up or down. Now take the midpoints of the 2 newly created line segments and move them randomly up or down. Repeat this process recursively until you’re at the resolution you need.

This is called the midpoint displacement algorithm.

Comment: Is there anywhere where the midpoint displacement algorithm has been used for generating data? This seems like a fairly good idea.

Comment: @Sharan. Probably some of those physics students I mentioned in the comment to your question :)

Comment: @SharanDuggirala I've mainly seen it used in simulating lighting in video production. I've not seen it used for generating data, but it occurred to me that it could work in this case.